# Finding the permanent of a matrix

Tags: combinatorics, permanent

I am trying to find the permanent of a $n\times n $ ($n\geq 4$) matrix $A_n$ of the form
$$ \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\cdots& 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \cdots& 0 &0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 &0 \cdots& 0  &0 \\
\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\ddots& \vdots &\vdots \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0&0& 0 \cdots &1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0&0& 0 \cdots& 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}  $$
But I haven't had much luck. There is a hint for this problem though:

> Let $B_n$ be the permanent of $A_n$ and calculate $B_n$ by expanding by the first row and column. Show that $B_n = B_{n−1}+
> B_{n−2} − 2$. So $\{B_n − 2 | n \geq 3\}$ is a Fibonacci sequence.

I wasn't able to prove $B_n = B_{n−1}+
B_{n−2} − 2$; the rest is clear.

Comment: How are $B_{n-1}$ and $B_{n-2}$ conformable if they have different dimensions?

Comment: @Golden_Ratio Sorry my bad, $A_n$ is the matrix and $B_n$ is its permanent!